# XML File Model Mapping asp.net MVC3 ( Dynamically Map an xml file to a model class asp.net mvc3 )

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.3, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to implement a payment gateway(INTUIT payment gateway). I would like to serialize an xml to an model class and save into my database. I am using Desktop Model for intuit payment gateway, as the hosted model is a pain to get working with especially ssl certificates, so i dont want to try that.

I must mention i am able to get the response using the below mentioned code, where i am stuck at the moment is serialize the xml and save the response into the database. This xml is pulled from a folder in my xmlfiles folder located in my project.

For sample xml format, check out this one. https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/qbms/0060_Documentation/Sending_Requests

this is an xml file i am trying to post to url (https://merchantaccount.ptc.quickbooks.com/j/AppGateway)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?qbmsxml version="4.5"?>
<QBMSXML>
    <SignonMsgsRq>
        <SignonDesktopRq>
            <ClientDateTime>2012-07-25T17:13:45</ClientDateTime>
            <ApplicationLogin>abc.abc.us</ApplicationLogin>
            <ConnectionTicket>TGT-1-g42FGaMfOTQ82GcWFBpsuQ</ConnectionTicket>
        </SignonDesktopRq>
    </SignonMsgsRq>
    <QBMSXMLMsgsRq>
        <CustomerCreditCardChargeRq>
            <TransRequestID>4540453787200</TransRequestID>
            <CreditCardNumber>4111111111111111</CreditCardNumber>
            <ExpirationMonth>12</ExpirationMonth>
            <ExpirationYear>2016</ExpirationYear>
            <IsCardPresent>false</IsCardPresent>
            <Amount>10.00</Amount>
        </CustomerCreditCardChargeRq>
    </QBMSXMLMsgsRq>
</QBMSXML>
```

The Controller i use to make a post to the url

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    WebRequest req = null;
    WebResponse rsp = null;
    string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/XMLData/XMLFile1.xml");
    string uri = "https://merchantaccount.ptc.quickbooks.com/j/AppGateway";
    req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    //req.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy(); // Enable if using proxy
    req.Method = "POST";        // Post method
    req.ContentType = "application/x-qbmsxml";     // content type

    // Wrap the request stream with a text-based writer
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
    // Write the XML text into the stream
    writer.WriteLine(this.GetTextFromXMLFile(fileName));
    writer.Close();
    // Send the data to the webserver
    rsp = req.GetResponse();
   // var resp = (Object)rsp.GetResponseStream();
    if (rsp != null)
    {
        StreamReader inStream = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
        var data = inStream.ReadToEnd();

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(data);
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/XMLData/SampleXmlE2E.xml");
        xmlDoc.Save(path);//regenerates the xml file in different system.
    }

    return View();
    //XElement root = new XElement("root");
    //root.Add(new XElement("element1"));
    //root.Add(new XElement("element2"));
    //root.Add(new XAttribute("attribute1", "a value"));
    //return new XmlResult(root);
}

private string GetTextFromXMLFile(string file)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
    string ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    return ret;
}

private string SendRequest(Uri UriObj, string data)
{
    string _result;

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UriObj);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "text/xml";
    var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    writer.Write(data);
    writer.Close();

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
    var streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);

    _result = streamRead.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    streamRead.Close();
    streamResponse.Close();
    response.Close();
    return _result;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varun,

**[Edit -update]**

Based on this XML:

```
<?qbmsxml version="4.5"?>
<QBMSXML>
  <SignonMsgsRq>
    <SignonDesktopRq>
      <ClientDateTime>2012-07-25T17:13:45</ClientDateTime>
      <ApplicationLogin>app.app.login.url</ApplicationLogin>
      <ConnectionTicket>TGT-1-g42FGaMfOTQ82GcWFBpsuQ</ConnectionTicket>
    </SignonDesktopRq>
  </SignonMsgsRq>
  <QBMSXMLMsgsRq>
    <CustomerCreditCardChargeRq>
      <TransRequestID>4540453787200</TransRequestID>
      <CreditCardNumber>4111111111111111</CreditCardNumber>
      <ExpirationMonth>12</ExpirationMonth>
      <ExpirationYear>2016</ExpirationYear>
      <IsCardPresent>false</IsCardPresent>
      <Amount>10.00</Amount>
    </CustomerCreditCardChargeRq>
  </QBMSXMLMsgsRq>
</QBMSXML>
```

Here's the class structure that you'd need to deserialize into as per the example above:

```
[XmlRoot("QBMSXML")]
public class QbmsXml
{
    [XmlElement("SignonMsgsRq")]
    public SignonMsgsRq SignonMsgsRq { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("QBMSXMLMsgsRq")]
    public QbmsXmlMsgsRq QbmsXmlMsgsRq { get; set; }
}

public class SignonMsgsRq
{
    [XmlElement("SignonDesktopRq")]
    public SignonDesktopRq SignonDesktopRq { get; set; }
}

public class SignonDesktopRq
{
    [XmlElement("ClientDateTime")]
    public DateTime ClientDateTime { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ApplicationLogin")]
    public string ApplicationLogin { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ConnectionTicket")]
    public string ConnectionTicket { get; set; }
}

public class QbmsXmlMsgsRq
{
    [XmlElement("CustomerCreditCardChargeRq")]
    public CustomerCreditCardChargeRq CustomerCreditCardChargeRq { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerCreditCardChargeRq
{
    [XmlElement("TransRequestID")]
    public Int64 TransRequestID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CreditCardNumber")]
    public string CreditCardNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ExpirationMonth")]
    public int ExpirationMonth { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ExpirationYear")]
    public int ExpirationYear { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("IsCardPresent")]
    public bool IsCardPresent { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Amount")]
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Just use the xmlSerialiser along the lines of:

```
class Program
{
    private static T DeSerialize<T>(string fromXmlFile) where T: class
    {
        if (!File.Exists(fromXmlFile))
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        T deserializedClass;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        // ToDo: add error catching etc
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fromXmlFile))
        {
            deserializedClass = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return deserializedClass;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var yourXmlFilePath = @"d:\temp\xmltest.xml";
        var deserializedClass = DeSerialize<QbmsXml>(yourXmlFilePath);

        Console.WriteLine(deserializedClass
                            .QbmsXmlMsgsRq
                            .CustomerCreditCardChargeRq.Amount);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: It runs but always returns null, I have ensured that the file name is fetched and it does load the xml.

Comment: public ViewResult Index()
        {
           var yourXmlFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/XMLData/XMLFile1.xml");
            var deserializedClass = DeSerialize<QbmsXml>(yourXmlFilePath);
            return View();
        }

Comment: varun, in the xml DeSerialize method, what happens inside the using block?? Also, try knocking up a simple console app and copying the code from my answer and see what happens there too. Finally, you do realise that you're not passing anything into your Index View. your return value should be `return View(deserializedClass);` and your Index.cshtml should have a model defined of type QbmsXml, i.e `@model yournamespace.Models.QbmsXml`

Comment: For some reason it still gives me null values. I just ran your project using console application. See this is the screenshot. <www.ibistage.com/nullvalues.jpg>

Comment: Also this is the class model file <www.ibistage.com/qbmsmodel.jpg> thanks for your time.

Comment: varun - can you confirm that XMLFile1.xml is the same as the one that you posted in your question as this is what I based my xml entry on. if not, drop the contents of that file into the question and I'll update the object model for that asap.

Comment: varun, this is mad :-). i tried this by copy pasting my own answer (plus the xml section) out into my laptop and created a new project with the xml saved in a file. it all worked as planned. I can't figure what the issue might be. can you 'send' me your actual xmlfile1.xml file (my email address is in my profile) in case there are some subtle differences between the two and I can examine that locally?

Comment: Seems like i am lost! <www.ibistage.com/qbms.zip>

Comment: varun - thanks for the zip. unfortunately, no xmlfile1.xml included. can you redo it with that attached and I'll fix it all up as required and/or make comments on what you need to do

Comment: Jim, XML file i mentioned in the question is the same file i have in my c drive. thank u.

Comment: hi varun, the actual xml file that you are trying to use 'may' have something slightly different to the one in the example, hence my request to pop that in a link/zip

Comment: hey varun, that file format is different from the one in your question!! i'll update as required

Comment: i am surprised, how would this throw a null value, i tried at my end as well. it must throw a run time error! if the xml schema doesn match with the class model, it must throw either compile time or run time error.

Comment: varun -see update in my answer for class based on your new xmlfile